# Using PHP explode() to parse multi-part error messages

Tags: php, array, parsing, error-handling

I am dealing with a system which sends any unexpected errors back to me in a string, for example:

```
Error Type - Database
Error Message - Error Executing Database Something is wrong.
Error Detail - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

Now to create a better UI I am expected to deal with these errors, so I thought about using `explode()`, and found this [user's response in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307) which helped me delimit the results with two `delimiters` instead of just one:

Then I needed to get a little deeper into the code because I wanted `$key => $val` pairs, so I came across [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966755/1527252).

Then I combined both and came across this solution:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);

    list($err_typ, $err_typ_cont,
         $err_mess, $err_mess_cont,
         $err_det, $err_det_cont) = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);

    $result[ trim($err_typ) ] = trim($err_typ_cont);
    $result[ trim($err_mess) ] = trim($err_mess_cont);
    $result[ trim($err_det) ] = trim($err_det_cont);
    return  $result;
}
```

Then I call the function like this:

```
 multiexplode(array("-", PHP_EOL), $errorMessage)
```

The response seems to be exactly what I needed:

```
Array
(
    [Error Type] => Database
    [Error Message] => Error Executing Database Something is wrong.
    [Error Detail] => [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '1'.
)
```

---

My question comes with PHP's best practices, and if there would be a more reliable or a more efficient approach I could take into solving this problem?

Comment: which delimeters are you using? I presume not the same from that PHP UCN (i.e. `",",".","|",":"`)

Comment: @SamOnela No, I am using `"-", PHP_EOL` The `-` to separate key from value, and `PHP_EOL` to create new item from string's new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- This function is designed to only deal with a very sepcific use case - parsing a formatted error string.  For that reason I would recommend changing the function name to be more representative of what is actually happening.  Perhaps something like `parseErrorString()` or similar.
- Since you are dealing with a very specific use case here, why would you require the caller to pass in the delimiters?  This function should fully encapsulate all the parsing logic.
- Using an array for return, seems odd, particularly since you have spaces in your key names.  I would consider returning a stdClass or similar object with `type`, `message`, `detail` properties.
- Though not strictly required, I would consider using regular expressions here, as I think that can clean things up as well as allow the solution to be less fragile to changes in the string format.
- Using `PHP_EOL` as line break may be fragile. `PHP_EOL` is good for working with strings within same environment, but may fail if your application is running in a different environment than the environment your string is produced in.
- Your function assumes happy path execution.  What if you get a poorly/unexpectedly formatted string?  Perhaps you are validating this string somewhere else, but if not, you should do it here in your function.

A refactoring, with these thoughts in mind, might yield something like the following:

```
function parseErrorString($string) {
    if(empty($string) || !is_string($string)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Non-zero length string expected');
    }
    $lines = preg_split('/\R/', $string);
    $error = array_reduce(
        $lines,
        function (&$err, $line) {
            $regex = '/^Error (Type|Message|Detail) - (.*)$/';
            $matches = [];
            $result = preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
            if ($result !== 1) {
                // no match.  Is this an error condition?
                // at the very least, do nothing
                return $err;
            }
            $err->{strtolower($matches[1])} = $matches[2];
            return $err;
        },
        new stdClass();
    );
    return $error;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` `on line <b>268</b>`

Comment: @Samuel code in CR answers isn't meant to be taken as-is (reviewers don't even *have* to supply code), it's meant to illustrate a point.

Comment: Okay, I was just trying to build off the code you offered; I was testing it to see how it would work.

Comment: @Samuel Sorry have been writing too much javascript lately I guess, and had syntax error.

Comment: It's alright... I've never been a javascript guy...

Answer (score 2):

This task seems simple enough to me.  I only recommend that you limit the explosion performed on each line, then it won't matter if the delimiter is duplicated later in the line.  Clean, reliable, fast.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BlbKu))

```
function parseErrorMessage($string) {
    foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $string) as $line){  // split on end of lines
        list($label,$message)=explode(' - ',$line,2);  // limit the explosion to 2 elements
        $result[$label]=$message;  // preserve using first half and second half of line
    }
    return $result;
}

$string ="Error Type - Database
Error Message - Error Executing Database Something is wrong.
Error Detail - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '1'.";

print_r(parseErrorMessage($string));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Error Type] => Database
    [Error Message] => Error Executing Database Something is wrong.
    [Error Detail] => [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '1'.
)
```

---

If you are concerned that your error messsage substring may contain line breaks, then regex is better suited.

The code to follow will break the string into a 1-dimensional array of alternating `labels` and `messages` before pairing them with `array_chunk()` then assigning them as your desired key-value pairs with `array_combine()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UECG1))

```
function parseErrorMessage($string) {
    $pairs=array_chunk(preg_split('/\R*(Error \w+) - /',$string,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE),2);
    return array_combine(array_column($pairs,0),array_column($pairs,1));
}

$string ="Error Type - Database
Error Message - Error Executing Database Something is wrong.
Error Detail - [Macromedia]
[SQLServer JDBC Driver]
[SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '1'.";

var_export(parseErrorMessage($string));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Error Type' => 'Database',
  'Error Message' => 'Error Executing Database Something is wrong.',
  'Error Detail' => '[Macromedia]
[SQLServer JDBC Driver]
[SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near \'1\'.',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [your comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179855/using-php-explode-to-parse-multi-part-error-messages#comment341531_179855):

> I am using "-", PHP_EOL The - to separate key from value, and PHP_EOL to create new item from string's new line

This makes me worry about the cases where one of the lines contains a hyphen (i.e. `-`), which would yield an incomplete string - see [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/mUdloIuH8fjv6ia9) for an illustration.

Mike's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179858/120114) is good. I agree the name could be made specific for parsing the error message, and that regular expressions could be utilized, though [explode()](http://php.net/explode) should suffice.

```
function parseErrorMessage ($string) {
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
    return array_reduce($lines, function($result, $line) {
        $lineParts = explode(' - ', $line);
        $key = array_shift($lineParts);
        $result[trim($key)] = join(' - ', $lineParts);
        return $result;        
    }, []);
}
```

This can be demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/xNRkoRlls3iKIu2u).